# Is it possible to embed a java swing application in a modern browser webpage?

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, embed

I created a simple **Java swing application**, and I want to embed it in an **html webpage**. I've searched online for answers, but nothing seems to work. I've already tried both **applets** and **Java web start** (Though I might be missing something). Is it possible to do so, and if so, how?

Thank you very much!

P.s. I'm asking this probably frequently asked question only because many of the old answers are not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

You might be interested in CheerpJ (https://leaningtech.com/pages/cheerpj.html)

CheerpJ is solution to run any Java application and applet via HTML5/WebAssembly/JavaScript. Both AWT and Swing UIs are fully supported. You can see a Swing based demo here: https://leaningtech.com/pages/swingdemo.html

Full disclosure: I am the lead dev of CheerpJ and CTO of Leaning Technologies, the company behind this product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wonder I've downloaded the CheerpJ Windows version, but I had a hard time understanding the tutorial, since I believe it is written for the Linux version. could you please explain how to turn my application into a webpage using it?

Comment: As explained in the tutorial (https://github.com/leaningtech/cheerpj-meta/wiki/Tutorial), the conversion is really just 1 command in the windows terminal or powershell. You will need to have Python 3 installed and available in the PATH.

If you need further help, please use our gitter channel (https://gitter.im/leaningtech/cheerpj) or open a specific question here on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=cheerpj)

Answer (score 1):

[Java Applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) tehnology is being phased out by both Oracle (owner of Java) and by the browser makers (Mozilla, Apple, Google, etc.).

Oracle is also phasing out [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start). See [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) of 2020-05.

An open-source fork of Java Web Start continues as [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/).

You might consider rebuilding your app as a [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web app, using form layout with widgets in a manner similar to Swing.